# Task.Wait not ending

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, wait

I have code that looks like this:

```
private static void Func1()
        {
            Task task = Func2();
            .
            .
            .
            task.Wait();
            Log("Func1 done");
        }

        private static async Task Func2()
        {
            var result = await someLib.Func3();
            Log("someLib.Func3 done");
        }
```

Running this I see a problem - Func1 is never ending. and I'm not sure why. someLib.Func3() do end but I also don't see the log for that ("someLib.Func3 done")

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: would be easier to get an answer if you post some code that actually anyone else can run or to explain a little about what someLib.Func3 is.

Comment: Wasn't able to create a snippet that reproduces it. someLib.Func3 is doing some web request.
I wanted more of a theory of why/how it can happen

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Thanks i think this is it